# How password hash algorithm for stateless basic authentication api?

Tags: java, spring, security, bcrypt

I have a `spring` webservice api that authenticates users from a properties file. The passwords are stored in `bcrypt` algorithm so far.

Problem: my api is stateless, thus any `basic auth` request will force bcrypt authentication to recalculate, causing delays of approx *100ms* on each request.

Question: which algorithm is advised to be used for encrypting user passwords (no matter if in properties file or db), that are to be used on every request on a stateless api?

With focus on authentication performance, but not neglecting security.

Comment: Handing out cookies that contain an authentication token / session id that has an expiration built-in and is signed by your application would not add state but remove the constant hashing overhead.

Comment: I know, but I cannot add cookie/token to the auth. I just have to stick with `basic auth` stateless.

Comment: If you're not adding a token, are you passing username and password on every call?  That's less secure than adding a token.  Look into JWT, which is built on basic auth.

Comment: Being slow is one of the primary **benefits** of bcrypt. You're asking for that benefit to be removed. You're also asking for "encryption" of passwords which is a **terrible** idea and if you don't know the difference between hashing and encryption you should not be allowed near the implementation of such a security system anyway. Sorry to be so blunt, but this is really not the right place to roll your own.

Comment: Well, my only goal is having a quite-security properties file with a bunch of users. If that properties file gets compromised, I have to store the passwords hashed. Unfortunately, I cannot switch to any other than `basic auth`. So I have to find a trade-off between security and performance. `bcrypt` which I used so seem not to be the correct hashing algorithm, as written.

Comment: You certainly *can* add cookies / tokens to the auth, those are still stateless as I as said. If you want to stick to basic auth only then you will have to deal with intentionally high computation time. Weakening your authentication for convenience sake is a very bad idea and you will (probably) not get useful advise here on how to achieve that.

Comment: @luk2302 so then I'd have to tell my clients to authenticate once, and then just provide the cookie/token afterwards in followup requests?

Answer (score 3):

I'd skip encrypting the password and use tokens instead. One such solution is [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (Json Web Tokens) and Spring comes with support for them out of the box.

You can take a look at an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt).

You can go even further (this is what I do) and delegate all of this into an OAuth provider. I usually use [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) for this.

Answer (score -2):

In the end I decided to create a caching authentication handler. It cashes the password from basic auth, and the belonging hashed bcrypt string. But only if authentication was successful.

This way I can speed up known clients with valid authentications (as I won't have to recalculate the bcrypt hash match for them), but still keep the brutforce benefits from `bcrypt` algorithm.

As follows the spring-specific implementation:

```
static class CachingDelegatingPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {
        private final PasswordEncoder delegate = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        private final Map<String, String> cache = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            return delegate.encode(rawPassword);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            String cachedPassword = cache.get(rawPassword);
            if (cachedPassword != null && StringUtils.equals(cachedPassword, encodedPassword))
                return true;

            boolean match = delegate.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword);
            if (match) cache.put(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);

            return match;
        }
}

@Configuration
static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider p = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        p.setPasswordEncoder(new CachingDelegatingPasswordEncoder());
        p.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        p.afterPropertiesSet();
        builder.authenticationProvider(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: You now have plaintext passwords in your application memory, not a good idea either. At that point your are not much better off than just keeping the password in a plaintext file. There is a VERY good reason you get the password as a `CharSequence` and not a `String` - the reason is that you want to be able to clean the memory asap after the password was used. `String`s may be interned into the string pool, keeping the password in memory even longer.